I've written an x86 16-bit real mode Assembly kernel, but it doesn't work as planned and I don't know why
I have a problem with my x86 16-bit real mode Assembly kernel.
Here below there are all the files I used to do this, including the bootloader:
     File (routine): dload.asm

DLOAD:
    PUSHA
    MOV AH, 0X02
    
    MOV AL, 0X04
    MOV CH, 0X00
    MOV CL, 0X02
    MOV DH, 0X00
    MOV DL, BL
    MOV BX, 0X0000
    MOV ES, BX
    MOV BX, 0X7E00
    
    INT 0X13
    JC DERRR

DSUCC:
    POPA
    MOV AL, 0X00
    RET

DERRR:
    POPA
    MOV AL, 0X01
    RET

     File (routine): screen.asm

SHOW_BASIC_SCREEN:
    PUSHA
    
    MOV AH, 0X0E
    MOV BX, PNAME_OFFSET
    MOV CX, 20
    
SHOW_PNAME:
    MOV AL, [BX]
    
    CMP CX, 0
    JE SHOW_PNAME_END
    
    INT 0X10
    
    INC BX
    DEC CX
    
    JMP SHOW_PNAME
    
SHOW_PNAME_END:
    MOV AL, '@'
    
    INT 0X10
    INT 0X10
    
    MOV CX, 18

AFTER_PNAME_SPACES:
    MOV AL, ' '
    
    CMP CX, 0
    JE END_SPACING
    
    INT 0X10
    
    DEC CX
    
    JMP AFTER_PNAME_SPACES

END_SPACING:
    MOV AL, '@'
    
    INT 0X10
    INT 0X10
    
    MOV AL, ' '
    INT 0X10

    MOV AL, '}'
    INT 0X10
    
    MOV CX, 36
    
SHOW_INPUT_SPACE:
    MOV AL, ' '
    
    CMP CX, 0
    JE END_INPUT_SPACE
    
    INT 0X10
    
    DEC CX
    JMP SHOW_INPUT_SPACE

END_INPUT_SPACE:
    MOV CX, 20

CLOSE_PNAME:
    MOV AL, '='
    
    CMP CX, 0
    JE CLOSE_PNAME_END
    
    INT 0X10
    
    INC BX
    DEC CX
    
    JMP CLOSE_PNAME

CLOSE_PNAME_END:
    MOV CX, 22

CLOSE_SPACES:
    MOV AL, ' '
    
    CMP CX, 0
    JE CLOSE_SPACES_END
    
    INT 0X10
    
    DEC CX
    
    JMP CLOSE_SPACES

CLOSE_SPACES_END:
    MOV CX, 38

CLOSE_INPUT:
    MOV AL, '='
    
    CMP CX, 0
    JE CLOSE_INPUT_END
    
    INT 0X10
    
    DEC CX
    
    JMP CLOSE_INPUT

CLOSE_INPUT_END:
    POPA
    RET

PNAME_OFFSET EQU 0X8E00

     File (routine): cscr.asm

CSCR:
    PUSHA
    
    MOV CX, 25
    MOV AH, 0X0E
    
CSCR_LOOP:
    MOV AL, 10
    
    CMP CX, 0
    JE CSCR_END
    
    INT 0X10
    
    DEC CX
    JMP CSCR_LOOP

CSCR_END:
    MOV AH, 0X2
    MOV BH, 0X0
    MOV DH, 0X0
    MOV DL, 0X0
    
    INT 0X10
    
    POPA
    RET

     File (routine): input.asm

INPUT_CHR:
    PUSHA
    MOV AH, 0X0
    
    INT 0X16
    MOV [BX], AL
    
    POPA
    RET

INPUT_STR:
    PUSHA

INPUT_STR_LOOP:
    MOV AH, 0X0
    INT 0X16
    
    CMP AL, 0XD
    JE INPUT_STR_END
    
    MOV AH, 0X0E
    INT 0X10
    
    MOV [BX], AL
    INC BX
    JMP INPUT_STR_LOOP

INPUT_STR_END:
    POPA
    RET

     File (routine): print.asm

PRINT_CHR:
    PUSHA
    MOV AH, 0X0E
    
    MOV AL, [BX]
    INT 0X10
    
    POPA
    RET

PRINT_STR:
    PUSHA
    MOV AH, 0X0E

PRINT_STR_LOOP:
    MOV AL, [BX]
    
    CMP AL, 0X0
    JE END_PRINT_STR
    
    INT 0X10
    
    INC BX
    JMP PRINT_STR_LOOP

END_PRINT_STR:
    POPA
    RET

     File: boot.asm

[ORG 0X7C00]

__MAIN:
    MOV BX, DSKL_MSG
    CALL PRINT_STR
    
    MOV BL, DL
    CALL DLOAD
    
    CMP AL, 0X01
    JE __ERR
    
    MOV BX, DONE_DSKL_MSG
    CALL PRINT_STR
    
    MOV BX, KSTART_MSG
    CALL PRINT_STR
    
    JMP KOFFSET
    
__ERR:
    MOV BX, ERRR_DSKL_MSG
    CALL PRINT_STR

    JMP __END

DSKL_MSG:
    DB "Loading disk at 0x0000:0x7e00...", 10, 13, 0

DONE_DSKL_MSG:
    DB "Disk loaded successfully at 0x0000:0x7e00.", 10, 13, 0

ERRR_DSKL_MSG:
    DB "Fatal: unable to read disk. Cannot load kernel and boot the system.", 10, 13, 0

KSTART_MSG:
    DB "Starting kernel... ", 10, 13, 0

KOFFSET EQU 0x7E00

%INCLUDE "print.asm"
%INCLUDE "dload.asm"

__END:
    JMP $
    
    TIMES 510 - ( $ - $$ ) DB 0X0
    DW 0XAA55

     File: kernel.asm

[ORG 0X7E00]
    
    MOV BX, KSTARTED_MSG
    CALL PRINT_STR

__MAIN:
    CALL CSCR
    
    CALL SHOW_BASIC_SCREEN
    
    MOV AH, 0X02
    MOV AL, 0X00
    MOV BH, 0X00
    MOV DH, 0X00
    MOV DL, 0X2D
    
    INT 0X10
    
    MOV BX, INPUT_ADDR
    CALL INPUT_STR
    
    JMP __MAIN
    
KSTARTED_MSG:
    DB "Kernel started successfully.", 10, 13, 0

INPUT_ADDR EQU 0X7F00

%INCLUDE "print.asm"
%INCLUDE "input.asm"
%INCLUDE "cscr.asm"
%INCLUDE "screen.asm"
    
    JMP $

I am on Windows and I used NASM to compile all this stuff.
So I copied the compiled boot.bin and kernel.bin into a main.bin file
using Windows cmd command copy boot.bin/b+kernel.bin/b main.bin.
After this, I runned the bochsrc.bxrc Bochs setup file:
floppya: 1_44=main.bin,status=inserted
boot: floppy

The bootloader does its work and the kernel is started successfully, clearing the screen (using the CSCR function contained in the cscr.asm routine file) and showing what I call a basic "screen" (function SHOW_BASIC_SCREEN file screen.asm) with the top-left side used to show an hypothetic running program name (stored somewhere in the memory) and the top-right side used to give the running program an input. At last, the cursor is set into the top-right side and the input function is executed.
The problem, I think, is that the final JMP __MAIN instruction in the kernel doesn't work properly, for some unknown reason. In fact, once the CALL INPUT_STR instruction is executed (picture 1), the input is typed (picture 2) and ENTER is pressed, the cursor goes in the line below, deleting all the = I've put to make the "graphics", but without re-drawing all the screen (picture 3). And so it remains freezed in that position, without taking any input or doing something else.
Picture 1:

Picture 2:

Picture 3:

Can anyone explain me what's the problem and help me to solve it?
Thank you very much and I hope you could understand my problem.

In first iteration of _MAIN You entered text at address 0x7F00 and there is screen.asm code. After jmp __MAIN program hangs inside call SHOW_BASIC_SCREEN, I think. In last part CLOSE_INPUT because Your entered data changed meaning of the code. Starting from these lines CMP CX, 0,JE CLOSE_INPUT_END.

Yes! It works now perfectly! Thank you very much!
